# Multiple threading in parallel

Tags: multithreading, task

I want to know about running multiple threads back to back and how the order of execution will flow . So i just created a console application to know in depth about the threading concepts.

Please find the code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> task = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<=100; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task task1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => Directory.CreateDirectory("D://Dummy"+i+""));
            task.Add(task1);
        }
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(task.ToArray());
        foreach(var tasks in task)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task Id {0} IsCompleted {1} Status {2} IsFaulted {3} ", tasks.Id, tasks.IsCompleted, tasks.Status, tasks.IsFaulted);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When i execute the above code i ran into some queries as listed below

1)When i hit the break point in the first for loop am able to create folders but not when i just executed the console. Folder creates for the last iterated value(101) actually the last value is 100 but also dont know how 101 came?

2)The order of thread processing goes randomly not in the order as the one in the queue

Answer (score 0):

if u want to run thread in order use synchronized key word in methos
example-

```
public synchronized void methodName() {}
```

Comment: Then why the process doesn't executes as expected . 100 folders doesn't get created'

Comment: in loop u write condition 
'for(int i = 0 ; i<=100; i++)'
it execute 101 time then how u expect 100

Comment: 100 folders should get created as per the code but creates when debugging not when without break point

Comment: I am not getting you properly.

Comment: As per the code it should create 100 directories. It creates properly when i am having a break point inmy code and executed one by one. But not when i run the console application .Can you get?

Comment: can i get any udpate . Can  you able to get what am coming to say

Comment: yes now i get u but can u tell me how many time this loop will be executed
for(int i = 0 ; i<=100; i++)
        {
            //output
        }

Comment: 101 times it will get executed. But the problem is why the directory creates when the code was in debug mode with breakpoints but not when executing the console application